# How to get the name of file from uploaded file before save it to local path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have code like this:

```
public ActionResult Import(string excel, HttpPostedFileBase excelfile)
{

            if (excelfile == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("excel", "Please Input the file!");
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "DataUpload");
                return View("Index");
            }
            .........
  }
```

I want to get the name of excelfile and check it whether the name is correct or not. If its correct then it will go to the next process. If not, it will return into view ("index"). How can I do it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `HttpPostedFileBase` has a `FileName` property that you should be able to reference with:

`var fileName = excelfile.FileName;`

NOTE: older browsers may not supply this value if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

var fname = excelfile.FileName;